# What happens when we raise a polynomial with a power how many roots do we get?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics, quadratic-forms, symmetric-polynomials

What happens if we square a quadratic equation?

For example $(x^2 +2x -4)^2$ how many roots will this question have?

Comment: Four, but they will not all be distinct.

Comment: All the roots of $x^2 + 2x - 4$ will become double roots.

Comment: $(x^2 +2x -4)^2 =0 \iff x^2 + 2x -4 =0\iff x =\frac{-2\pm\sqrt{20}}2=\frac -1\pm \sqrt 5$.  So $x^2 + 2x -4$ has two roots, $-1+\sqrt 5$ and $-1+\sqrt 5$ and $(x^2 +2x -4)^2$ has the *exact* same roots but they are double roots.  $(x^2 +2x -4) = (x+1+\sqrt 5)(x+1+\sqrt 5)(x+1-\sqrt 5)(x+1-\sqrt 5)$.  That's either $4$ or $2$ double roots depending on... your class.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$(x-A)\cdot (x-B)=0 \iff [(x-A)\cdot (x-B)]^2 =0$$

therefore, more in general, $p(x)=0$ and $(p(x))^n=0$ with $n\in \mathbb N$ have the same number of distinct roots.

Answer (score 0):

$[P(x)]^k = 0\iff P(x) = 0$.

So $P(x)^k$ will have the *exact* same roots as $P(x)$ but now that are "multiple roots".

.......

which probably needs a little clarification.

If $P(x) = a_mx^m  + ...... + a_1x + a_0$ is a polynomial of degree $m$ then we say it has $m$ roots...

*BUT*  some of the roots might not be real.  (Example $x^2 + 1$ means $x^2 =-1$ doesn't have any real solutions.  But it has two *complex* solutions $x = i$ and $x = -i$ where $i$ is an imaginary number with the property $i^2 =-1$.  Depending on your course *maybe* you say $x^2 + 1$ doesn't have any real roots, or you say it has $2$ complex roots.)

*AND* some of the roots might be multiple roots.  (Example $x^2 -4x + 4 = (x-2)^2$ has one "double root" $x = 2$.  As to whether yous say $x^2 -4x + 4$ has two roots: $2$ and $2$, or whether you say $x^2 -4x +4$ has *one* double root depends on your class).

So what ever roots $P(x)$ has $P(x)^k$ will have the exact same roots but the multiplicity of each root is $k$ times larger.

Example if $P(x) = (x-2)^2(x+3) = (x^2 - 4x + 4)(x+3) = x^3 -x^2 -8x+12$ has a double root of $2$ and a single root of $-3$ then

$P(x)^5 = [(x-2)^2(x+3)]^5= (x-2)^{10}(x+3)^5$ will have a 10times root of $2$ and a $5$ times root of $-3$.

Technically that is $15$ roots.